# Transparent overlapping bar plots

Tags: matlab

I want to have two transparent bar plots that overlape in one figure. I tried this way:

```
bar(list2(:,1),list2(:,2),'r','FaceAlpha',0.5)
hold on
bar(list1(:,1),list1(:,2),'g','FaceAlpha',0.5)
```

but the output is:
[image: bar plot]

Why the second plot is not transparent and has these strange strips? 
I use matlab 2016a

Comment: Try setting the `'LineWidth'` to 0 in the second plot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

your approach is correct, and it works for a few bars:

```
[list1(:,2),list1(:,1)] = hist(randn(200,1));
[list2(:,2),list2(:,1)] = hist([randn(100,1)-0.5 ; randn(100,1)+0.5]);

bar(list2(:,1),list2(:,2),'r','FaceAlpha',0.5)
hold on
bar(list1(:,1),list1(:,2),'g','FaceAlpha',0.5)
```

[image: Histogram]

However, you can notice that there are black lines contouring each bar. As the bar number increases, the black contours will cover everything:

```
[list1(:,2),list1(:,1)] = hist(randn(3000,1), 300);
[list2(:,2),list2(:,1)] = hist([randn(1500,1)-2 ; randn(1500,1)+2], 300);

h1 = bar(list2(:,1),list2(:,2),'r','FaceAlpha',0.5)
hold on
h2 = bar(list1(:,1),list1(:,2),'g','FaceAlpha',0.5)
```

[image: Dense histogram]

(The result will depend on the Matlab version. In 2016b it appears that the problem is automatically corrected).

The solution: remove the black contours:

```
h1.EdgeColor = 'none';
h2.EdgeColor = 'none';
```

[image: Dense histogram corrected]